# How to get total file size of multiple files upload using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I have a form where users can upload multiple files.

But I only want to allow them to do so when the **combined size** of all files does not exceed 3GB. How can I do this?

Here is my current code:

```js
var fileCount = 0;

var showFileCount = function() {
  $('#file_count').text('# Files selected: ' + fileCount);
};

showFileCount();

$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
  $(this).parents('span').remove();
  fileCount -= 1;
  showFileCount();
})

$('#uploadFile').on('change', function() {

  var filename = this.value;
  var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
  if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
  }
  var files = $('#uploadFile')[0].files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var fileSize = (files[i].size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2);
    if (files[i].size > 3204448256) {
      // $("#input-file-1").html(file_names);
      alert("You have exceeded maximum allowed size 3GB")
      return true;
    }

    $("#upload_prev").append('<span>' + '<div class="filenameupload">' + files[i].name + ' (' + fileSize + ' MB)</div>' + '<p class="close" >X</p></span>');
  }
  fileCount += files.length;
  showFileCount();
});
```

```css
.filenameupload {
  width: 98%;
}

#upload_prev {
  border: thin solid #000;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 1.5em 1em;
}

#upload_prev span {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="file_count"></div>
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="FileUpload" multiple="multiple" />
<div id="upload_prev"></div>
```

[**Same code, in JSFiddle**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vijayak7803/4ny3qna6/11/)

I have a form where users can upload multiple files.

But I only want to allow them to do so when the **combined size** of all files does not exceed 3GB. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't see a single question mark in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate file extension and size before submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096591/validate-file-extension-and-size-before-submitting-form)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible this is not a duplicate. He's asking how to check whether the **combined** size of all files exceeds 3GB

Comment: @blex, thanks for understanding my question., I have added my code in fiddle to check

Comment: @blex, can you pls guide me what is best title for this question, i am not good at english

Comment: @Test Your code seems to be working as expected. What is your problem?

Comment: @blex, if the all files size more than 3gb not to allow to upload file and show alert

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will get you close.

To determine the total uploaded filesize you will need to first loop over the files and sum all of the individual file sizes.
Then after you have the total file size from the upload, convert to GB for comparison and check if it is > 3GB. If it is, print the alert and return to prevent the file uploads.

```js
var fileCount = 0;

var showFileCount = function() {
  $('#file_count').text('# Files selected: ' + fileCount);
};

showFileCount();

$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
  $(this).parents('span').remove();
  fileCount -= 1;
  showFileCount();
})

$('#uploadFile').on('change', function() {

  var filename = this.value;
  var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
  if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
  }
  var files = $('#uploadFile')[0].files;
  var totalSize = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    // calculate total size of all files        
    totalSize += files[i].size;
  }
  //1x10^9 = 1 GB
  var sizeInGb = totalSize / 1000000000;
  if(sizeInGb > 3){
    alert("You have exceeded the maximum file upload size.");
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   var fileSize = (files[i].size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2);

    $("#upload_prev").append('<span>' + '<div class="filenameupload">' + files[i].name + ' (' + fileSize + ' MB)</div>' + '<p class="close" >X</p></span>');
    
  }
  fileCount += files.length;
  showFileCount();
});
```

```css
.filenameupload {
  width: 98%;
}

#upload_prev {
  border: thin solid #000;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 1.5em 1em;
}

#upload_prev span {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="file_count"></div>
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="FileUpload" multiple="multiple" />
<div id="upload_prev"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, Here you are allowing user all files are more than 3GB, you are not allowing the user if one file size is more than 3GB

Comment: That is not true, if one of the files is > 3GB than the total file size would also be > 3GB and the method would return preventing the uploads from happening.

Comment: can you check above image i have uploaded latest